# Monkey patch for created_at

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, monkeypatching

I'm trying to write a monkey patch to add a method for created_at.

I created a date_time_extras.rb file and put it in the `lib` directory, with contents:

```
class DateTime
  def beginning_of_hour
    change(:min => 0)
  end
end
```

From the console I do:

```
record.created_at.beginning_of_hour
```

But this yields method missing errors. It looks like created_at isn't a datetime? Because `DateTime.new.beginning_of_hour` works, and `record.created_at.class` yields `ActiveSupport::TimeWithZone`.

So how do I write a monkey patch for created_at type dates?

I'm using rails version 3.0.10.

**Update**

Also tried

```
module ActiveSupport
  class TimeWithZone
    def beginning_of_hour
      change(:min => 0)
    end
  end
end
```

to no avail

Comment: Welp.. in the interim it looks like I can just use `record.created_at.change(:min => 0)`

Answer (score 0):

Did you try declaring it in `class Time`?

```
class DateTime
  def beginning_of_hour
    change(:min => 0)
  end
end
```

`TimeWithZone` looks like it delegates its time object to `Time` not `DateTime`.

Also `TimeWithZone` contains more than just the `@time` object so you would have to do something like

```
module ActiveSupport
  class TimeWithZone
    def beginning_of_hour
      self.time.change(:min => 0)
    end
  end
end
```

But I'm not 100% sure on that code.